# Spring Endpoints Returning Blank (not error 404)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, rest

Recently, I updated my spring to extend JPARepository and added an actuator and logging, and now my REST endpoints take 10 seconds to load, and return a blank page. Please note, the methods associated with the endpoints run successfully, so when I put in a system.out.print and other DB queries, they execute successfully, but none of the method return to the api endoint. Here are some examples of how my project looks for the entity, repository, service, controller, and application.properties:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Example")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ExampleEntity {

//specific code removed for security

}
```

Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface ExapleRepository extends JPARepository<ExampleEntity, String> {

}
```

Service:

```
   @Service
public class ExampleService {
    @Autowired
    ExampleRepository exampleRepository;
//methods in here
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("running");
return "Test Successful";
//when going to localhost:8081/test, this method will system.out.println running, but postman will run for like 10 seconds, and return nothing
    }

}
```

Application.properties:

```
spring.data.jdbc.repositories.enabled=false
#Basic Server IP Settings
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{dbname}
spring.datasource.username={hidden}
spring.datasource.password={hidden}
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
#server.address=10.0.0.78
#insert ifconfig inet ip
server.port=8081

#Flyway Settings
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true

#Actuator Settings
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/{hidden}
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Here are some images for reference...

[image]

[image]

As you can see, when I go to the endpoint, the method runs successfully, but the string is never successfully returned to the rest endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, you mind posting the current response and what you expect it to be? Is it the case you need to wrap the response object inside a ResponseEntity<>?

Comment: Sure! So if you look at the current code, if I go to localhost:8081/test, I should get "Test Successful" on my browser/postman, and "running" on my springboot program console. Right now, the only thing I get is a "running" on my springboot console, but nothing appears on my browser/postman. Ill attach a picture to my question shortly to illustrate that.

Comment: I see your point, did it only start when you fired up the management endpoints/actuator? I mean, removing the dependencies (or disabling via configuration) makes it work back again?

another check: have you tried using curl instead of POSTMAN ? 

curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8081/test'

Comment: To be completely honest, not sure, because all changes were made in 1 commit (bad practice, I know :() I also know I changed my package structure, and had to change from CRUDRepository to JPARepository, although I am not quite sure if that has to do with anything.

Comment: oh..you mentioned packages. Can you share the location of your main class (the runner)? IT should be in the root package one level above other components.

Comment: Sure! Just added it :)

Comment: @JasonChan I see you are using @RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
According to resource below
  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-customize-http-endpoints
this @RepositoryRestResource(exported = false) stops the Rest methods being exposed to API. I think the problem is there

Comment: I always have used @RepositoryRestResource(exported = false) to prevent users from seeing that this is a repository externally, but it has always worked before. I have also replaced it with @Repository, and I still get the same issues :(

Comment: There is too little information. Not sure why you changed to `JpaRepository` as that shouldn't be needed, please don't use `@Repository` on Spring Data repository interfaces as that only hurts the eyes and adds nothing. Please provide a sample that reproduces this (or link to your project).

Answer (score 1):

I have cloned your controller and it's working fine in my application, it prints both the console and the output on the screen. Try removing the (exported=false) from your repository as @Lakshman Kumar suggests may be that works.
I'm attaching the screen shots of your code and its output in my server for your reference,

[image: Output in browser]
[image: Code snippet and output in console]
[image: API response in postman]

Comment: Heyo! I tried that :) but still same issue. I have also tried to reach the endpoint with postman, curl and chrome, all to no avail. I will try another OS just to make sure its not a problem, but as for the exported = false, I have removed that and replaced all annotations with @repository instead. It seems to still be broken :(

Comment: I think we can try updating the Controller method to a ResponseEntity which wraps the string and check whether this works out in your case.

Comment: @RestController
public class DefaultController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity test() {
        System.out.println("running in default controller");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Test ran Successful", HttpStatus.OK);
//when going to localhost:8081/test, this method will system.out.println running, but postman will run for like 10 seconds, and return nothing
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out! thank you guys for your help so much! It turns out I had a logging service that was intercepting and causing my response to never finish returning. It looked like this

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
throws ServletException, IOException {
//code to log
}
```

I will need to find another way to log inputs but I think we should be set otherwise! Thank you so much guys! Sending upvotes your way!